# Get value of x-value from max y-value - python

Tags: python, indexing, max, mean

I'm trying to get extract the x-value from the maximum y-value in python. This is what I've got so far:

```
# reading Hanford and Livingston signals
# read hanford measurement
h1_name, h1_start_time, h1_strain = read_data(join(path, "H-H1_LOSC_4_V2-1126259446-32.hdf5"))

# read livingston measurement
l1_name, l1_start_time, l1_strain = read_data(join(path, "L-L1_LOSC_4_V2-1126259446-32.hdf5"))

# zero-padded FFT or DFT
x_hat = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(sc.hann(len(h1_strain)) * h1_strain))

t = np.linspace(0, 32, len(h1_strain))

plt.figure('h1_strain')
sig_xH = plt.plot(t, h1_strain, label='$x_{H}[n]$ signal')
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('strain')
plt.legend()
plt.figure('l1_strain')
sig_xL = plt.plot(t, l1_strain, label='$x_{L}[n]$ signal', color='blue')
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('strain')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE MAX, MIN AND MEAN VALUE OF THE PLOT BELOW ON THE X-AXIS FOR THE TIME
print('2 b)', min(h1_strain), '= minimum value signal h1_strain')
print('2 b)', max(h1_strain), '= maximum value signal h1_strain')
print('2 b)', np.mean(h1_strain), '= mean value signal h1_strain')
print('2 b)', min(l1_strain), '= minimum value signal h1_strain')
print('2 b)', max(l1_strain), '= maximum value signal h1_strain')
print('2 b)', np.mean(l1_strain), '= mean value signal h1_strain')
```

I´ve tried using the index()-function. This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
my_list.index(max(my_list))
```

which would return the x-value of the maximum y-value.

If you have multiple x-values with the same y-value, then the first x-value on the timescale will be returned.

In what sense doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I want to extract the value/index on the x-axis (time) which is at the same place as max(h1_strain) on the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used the numpy.where function:

```
# Find index of max and min values
max_h1_index = np.where(h1_strain == max(h1_strain))
min_h1_index = np.where(h1_strain == min(h1_strain))
max_l1_index = np.where(l1_strain == max(l1_strain))
min_l1_index = np.where(l1_strain == min(l1_strain))

# Find time of max and min values
print('2 b)', max_h1_index[0] / f_s, '= maximum value h1_strain time')
print('2 b)', min_h1_index[0] / f_s, '= minimum value h1_strain time')
print('2 b)', max_l1_index[0] / f_s, '= maximum value l1_strain time')
print('2 b)', min_l1_index[0] / f_s, '= minimum value l1_strain time')
```